# Android AsyncTask AlertDialog not Show

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to show an AlertDialog in my AsyncTask on onCancelled. My task is stopping properly, but the dialog isn't appearing. Here's my code below... Need help. Thanks...

```
public class getWebPage extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

protected void onPreExecute(String f) {
    // TODO Setting up variables
    f = "f";
}

protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Looper.prepare();
    DefaultHttpClient urlClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet getHtml = new HttpGet(PAGE_URL);
    ResponseHandler<String> resHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    try {
        String htmlPage = urlClient.execute(getHtml, resHandler);
        Log.d("Html Page", htmlPage);
        confessionsPage = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "ConfessionsPage.html");
        if (!confessionsPage.exists()) {
            confessionsPage.createNewFile();
        }
        writer = new PrintWriter(confessionsPage, "UTF-8");
        writer.print(htmlPage.replace("<!--", "").replace("-->", ""));
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(confessionsPage, "UTF-8", "http://www.facebook.com/");
        if (doc.title().contains("Welcome to Facebook")) {
            aDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(OpeningActivity.this).create();
            aDialog.setTitle("Restricted Access");
            aDialog.setMessage("Looks like your Confessions Page only allows login access. You may be logged in right now, but the app" +
                    " can't. Tell your page admin to allow non-logged in access for your confessions page.");
            aDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    aDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            getWebPage.this.cancel(true);
        }
```

and here is my on cancelled method:

```
    @Override
protected void onCancelled() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCancelled();
    aDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: to do ui actions from another thread you need to use the `post()` method of the parent view

Answer (score 0):

Try move everything from the `doInBackground` to the `onCancelled`.

So this will be your `onCancelled`:

```
AlertDialog aDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(OpeningActivity.this).create();
aDialog.setTitle("Restricted Access");
aDialog.setMessage("Looks like your Confessions Page only allows login access. You may be logged in right now, but the app" +
                        " can't. Tell your page admin to allow non-logged in access for your confessions page.");
aDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       aDialog.dismiss();
   }
});
aDialog.show();
```

And remove everything from the `doInBackground`.

Alternatively you can put this into your `AsyncTask`'s `onPostExecute` too and change the result type of the task to `Boolean`. in the `onPostExecute` check the result. If it's false and you need to display this error. display it from there. 
Note that `onPostExecute` is executed by the UI thread so you don't need the `runOnUiThread` stuff.

Comment: @StinePike Yeah I was wrong. it's already on the UI thread. but maybe the problem is you have to set all the AlertDialog options from the UI thread. BTW I don't see where you constructed `aDialog` in your code.

Comment: aDialog is constructed in the beginning of the Activity Class along with all the other variables, on the UI thread

Comment: hi i tried putting everything in the onCancelled and it didn't work. And i can't put it in the post execute. The reason i put the cancel code is so that it never reaches the postExecute.

Comment: There are some reasons that it won't reach the postExecute. The AsyncTask is really sensitive on the name of the function and whether you override the original function or not. When your return type is Boolean it should be exactly `public void onPostExecute(Boolean result)` with the `@Override` annotation, or it won't execute it.

Comment: But i don't want it to reach the postExecute. I want it to stop in the middle. I have code after the `aDialog` that i don't want to run.